# Remover tecla pressionada numa input text

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho o seguinte cenário: Uma `input text` que vem com um determinado valor/texto da BD mas que o utilizador não deve poder editar. Para tal, ao pressionar uma tecla na `input` vai apagar esse mesmo carácter pressionado.

O que estou fazendo é: uso o `keydown` na `input`, passo o evento da tecla:

`<input type="text" value="Texto da base de dados" keydown="apagaLetra(this)" />`

Agora na função `js` é que não sei bem o que fazer. Consigo saber qual a tecla pressionada com o `e.which`, agora apagar é que não estou a ver como se faz.

O resultado final é: Quando o utilizador pressiona uma tecla na input, a partir do JS faço `backspace`

Comment: É como se tu desse um backspace no input?

Comment: É exactamente isso @FelipeAvelar, como se desse um backspace

Comment: @GustavoRodrigues, como confirmei ao Felipe Avelar o que quero é: Dar backspace quando o utilizador insere um carácter. O Placeholder não é de perto solução para tal. Até porque se quiser copiar o conteúdo da input, e usar o placeholder é de todo impossível

Comment: Se o objetivo é não deixar o usuário editar o input, não seria mais fácil simplesmente utilizar o atributo ```readonly```?

Comment: @Kazzkiq, sim podia usar o `readonly`. A questão por vezes é os clientes que exigem certas "coisas" como esta :/ Mas já está resolvido :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solução só com HTML (`readonly`):

```
<input type="text" value="Texto da base de dados" readonly />
```

### Solução em javascript (jquery):

```
function travarInput(el){
    var v = el.val();
    el.on('keyup',function(){
       el.val(v); 
    });
}
```

#### Exemplo de ambas: [**`FIDDLE`**](http://jsfiddle.net/mGL7k/)

Answer (score 6):

Faça assim:

HTML:

```
<input id="foo" value="banco de dados">
```

JS:

```
var keydown = function(e) {    
    var $this = $(this);
    var valor_antigo = $this.val();

    $this.off("keydown");
    $this.on("keydown", function(){
        return false;    
    });

    $this.on("keyup", function(evt) {
         $this.val(valor_antigo);
         $this.off("keyup");

         $this.off("keydown");
         $this.on("keydown", keydown);
    });    
};

$("#foo").on("keydown", keydown);
```

Dá uma olhada neste fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3ZwF4/2/

O código é um pouco complexo pois é necessário previnir quando o usuário aperta uma tecla e segura.

Comment: Exactamente o que procurava! Obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Você poderia simplesmente impedir a ação da tecla retornando false:

### [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mhen9/)

Código:

```
$("#foo").on("keydown", function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode >= 32)
        return false;
});
```

Comment: A sua solução é interessante, contudo ela aceita que eu delete os caracteres utilizando ```backspace``` ou adicione novos caracteres utilizando ```alt``` + ```numero``` (ex.: ```alt``` + ```155```)

Comment: Esses casos teriam de ser adicionados à condição que retorna false. Vou dar uma melhorada nisso!